# Maven - how to build custom file structure including the output jar

Tags: maven, build

I am building app with following structure (where `myApp` is root):

```
myApp\bin\myApp.jar  
myApp\runMyApp.bat
```

So I need to 'wrap' the ouput jar in two directories and add to the outer directory myApp a script file.

How do I best set POM to do this?

Bonus question: I like the idea of making exe from bat. Currently I use a tool for that. Can something like this be achieved with Maven? Is having exe better than just bat file? (I did it mainly to insert the custom icon).

Answer (score 1):

First off the [AppAssembler](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) plugin can be used to create the `.bat` file for your `.jar`. It may not support the exact layout you are after, but it should be customizable to get something rather close.

Secondly, the [assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) plugin can then slurp all that up and produce a `.zip` file that has the layout you want and contains all the files you are after.

Other things to look into are the [NSIS](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/) which can create a `.exe` windows installer for your application.

Tools such as [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) can help wrap your entire application up in an `.exe` though I personally cannot find a nice *maven way* plugin for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the assembly plugin to create custom output directories and have found it very powerful. You can specify the archive format of the output folder like zip, etc and also relative paths to files that need to be included in the zip. Dependencies for your project are included in by adding in the below into your custom assembly xml file - this will add in all the dependent jars as specified in the pom.xml

```
<dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
```

Here is the link to the create your custom assembly descriptor - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html